# t-sql statement syntax error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax-error

Needing help with t-sql statement syntax error.  Full statement as per below.
Using sqlcmd on sql-server 2005.

```
-- oitm to oitg is a 1 to 1 link via the 64 matching columns
select g.[ItmsGrpNam], b.[ItmsGrpNam], count(1) 
from      oitg g
     join (select distinct 
           i.ItmsGrpCod as [ItmsGrpCod],
           i.QryGroup1 as [QryGroup1], 
           i.QryGroup2 as [QryGroup2] 
           from oitm i) p  -- pseudo intersect table for oitg-oitm links
     join oitb b  on b.[ItmsGrpCod] = p.[ItmsGrpCod]
where (g.ItmsGrpNam in  -- translate interect to oitg names
       (select x.ItmsGrpNam from oitg x where x.ItmsTypCod=1 and p.[QryGroup1]='Y') 
      )
group by g.ItmsGrpNam, b.ItmsGrpNam
```

Findings so far.

```
select g.[ItmsGrpNam], b.[ItmsGrpNam], count(1) 
from      oitg g
     join (select distinct 
           i.ItmsGrpCod as [ItmsGrpCod],
           i.QryGroup1 as [QryGroup1], 
           i.QryGroup2 as [QryGroup2] 
           from oitm i) p  -- pseudo intersect table for oitg-oitm links
     join oitb b  on b.[ItmsGrpCod] = p.[ItmsGrpCod]
```

This portion of statement gives the following error.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server , Line 10
Incorrect syntax near 'ItmsGrpCod'.

And the select within the above statement returns as it should.

```
3> select distinct
4>            i.ItmsGrpCod as [ItmsGrpCod],
5>            i.QryGroup1 as [QryGroup1],
6>            i.QryGroup2 as [QryGroup2]
7>            from oitm i
8> go
ItmsGrpCod QryGroup1 QryGroup2
---------- --------- ---------
       100 N         N
       101 N         Y
       102 N         Y
       103 N         Y
       104 N         Y
       105 N         Y
       106 N         Y
       107 N         N
       108 N         N
       108 Y         N
       110 N         Y
       111 N         N
       112 N         Y
       113 N         N
```

Have tried replacing "join" with "inner join".  Have started enclosing column names with square brackets.
ItmsGrpCod is the fk between oitm and oitb and is the same name. (not always the case in SAP land!)

For those interested this is my attempt at coding around the SAP B1 design flaw for the oitm (order items)
to oitg (item properties) no intersect table hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `on` statement for your first join. Perhaps something like this:

```
-- oitm to oitg is a 1 to 1 link via the 64 matching columns
select g.[ItmsGrpNam], b.[ItmsGrpNam], count(1) 
from      oitg g
     join (select distinct 
           i.ItmsGrpCod as [ItmsGrpCod],
           i.QryGroup1 as [QryGroup1], 
           i.QryGroup2 as [QryGroup2] 
           from oitm i) p  -- pseudo intersect table for oitg-oitm links
       on g.ItmsGrpCod = p.ItmsGrpCod
     join oitb b  on b.[ItmsGrpCod] = p.[ItmsGrpCod]
where (g.ItmsGrpNam in  -- translate interect to oitg names
       (select x.ItmsGrpNam from oitg x where x.ItmsTypCod=1 and p.[QryGroup1]='Y') 
      )
group by g.ItmsGrpNam, b.ItmsGrpNam
```

Comment: select g.[ItmsGrpNam], b.[ItmsGrpNam], count(1) 
    from      oitg g
         join (select distinct 
               i.ItmsGrpCod as [ItmsGrpCod],
               i.QryGroup1 as [QryGroup1], 
               i.QryGroup2 as [QryGroup2] 
               from oitm i) p  -- pseudo intersect table for oitg-oitm links
    on (g.ItmsGrpNam in  -- translate interect to oitg names
           (select x.ItmsGrpNam from oitg x where x.ItmsTypCod=1 and p.[QryGroup1]='Y') 
          )
         join oitb b  on b.[ItmsGrpCod] = p.[ItmsGrpCod]  
    group by g.ItmsGrpNam, b.ItmsGrpNam

Comment: Doh!  Not good with editing yet.   Hit return and it saves.  Anyway yes move the where clause up as an on clause and works.   Coming from a MySQL background and sure that I could have it either way.  Anyway, big thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the schema for these tables? Does oitb have a ItmsGrpCod column? SQL Server is pretty notorious for poor error reporting, but note that you use ItmsGrpCod four times in the query.

Comment: Good point.  I have the 2.5M help file but I renamed it to something more meaning full... trying to locate the link now.  Basically it is the SAP B1 SDK 8.81 table reference.chm.

Comment: [SDK_EN.chm](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/index?rid=/library/uuid/702faa60-4ab6-2c10-0b91-80d4fd923a76)

Comment: Being a newbie to t-sql am hoping that the syntax error is an easy find for experienced t-sql users.